# SQL Query Comparing Sales of Today to Last Year

Tags: sql-server

Using SQL Server 2008 and 
Using 'Today' value of 12/5/2017 for temporary data purposes.

I'm pulling gross sales per store for today and one year ago today (same day of the week). This is what I have so far:

```
     Declare @LastYearToday datetime, @Today datetime

    -- @LastYearToday is business day on selected date, last year, same weekday
    set @Today = '2017-12-5'
    set @LastYearToday = Convert(date, (DATEADD(year, -1, getdate()+1))) 

    SELECT 

      StoreID, GrossSales, DF_BusinessDay

    FROM DayFileSummary 

    WHERE 
    DF_BusinessDay = @LastYearToday OR 
    DF_BusinessDay = @Today

    ORDER BY StoreID
```

I need to subtract the Gross Sales of today from Gross Sales of last year, but am not sure how to proceed. Do I do this in the SQL or handle this in the report? It seems the report would need some logic to subtract only the gross sales with the same store ID but different dates. I feel like I'm over thinking this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(

    SELECT  
      StoreID, 
      SUM(CASE WHEN DF_BusinessDay = @LastYearToday 
               THEN GrossSales ELSE 0 END) AS LastYearGrossSales
      SUM(CASE WHEN DF_BusinessDay = @Today 
               THEN GrossSales ELSE 0 END) AS TodayGrossSales
    FROM DayFileSummary 
    WHERE DF_BusinessDay = @LastYearToday OR  DF_BusinessDay = @Today
    GROUP BY  StoreID

)
SELECT StoreID, LastYearGrossSales - TodayGrossSales AS Result
FROM CTE;
```

**Or:** use `UNION`:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT  
      StoreID, SUM(GrossSales) AS LastYearGrossSales, 0  AS TodayGrossSales
    FROM DayFileSummary 
    WHERE DF_BusinessDay = @LastYearToday 
    GROUP BY  StoreID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT StoreID, 0 AS LastYearGrossSales, SUM(GrossSales) AS TodayGrossSales
    FROM DayFileSummary 
    WHERE DF_BusinessDay = @Today
)
SELECT StoreID, SUM(LastYearGrossSales) - SUM(TodayGrossSales) AS Result
FROM CTE
GROUP BY StoreID
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks!